# WSL: This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My Windows computer crashed (blue screen), and when it came back up, none of the WSL VMs is working anymore. They're all in the "Stopped" state, and starting them gives the error

```
This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer
```

I tried to disable WSL feature, restart, enable it, restart, but got the same error.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling a WSL distribution, but when launching the new distribution, I get this error

```
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070531                                                                   
Error: 0x80070531 This user isn't allowed to sign in to this computer.
```

I am not sure what else I could try at this point. Does anyone know what this problem might be, or how I could get around it?

Comment: What WSL version is your instance?  What version of Windows are you running?  Please [edit] your question to include this vital information.  What is the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\CrashOnAuditFail`?

Comment: @Ramhound changing the value of that reg to 1 fixed the problem for me. Wanna post that as an answer? I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was reported that the following is a solution to this problem.

> 1. Save and clear the security event log (Event Viewer> Windows Logs> Security).
> 2. Start Registry Editor (Click on Start and type regedit).
> 3. Locate the following key, and then set the value of this key to 1: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\CrashOnAuditFail`
> 4. Restart the computer. The registry changes do not take effect until you restart the computer.

Source: [Cannot upgrade WSL1 to WSL2 distro #5678](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5678)